# How can I test microprocessor / microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it feasible to test microprocessor/microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26925/is-it-feasible-to-test-microprocessor-microcontroller)

As far as I know the manufacturers do it before shipment. 
How they test microprocessor / microcontroller? 
However, if I want to test  microprocessor / microcontroller by myself, how can I do it?

Comment: have you seen [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26925/is-it-feasible-to-test-microprocessor-microcontroller) question?

Comment: @stevenvh whoops I didn't notice :) Anyway, this doesn't make the question less duplicate do me.